# Why not every type are throw exceptions?

Tags: exception, d

"Only the types that are inherited from the Throwable class can be thrown".
Could anybody  explain me. Why *not* every type are throwable? If in doc there no mention about function can throw exception, it's mean that it do not have exception?

For example I thought that next try-catch block would work. But it is not.

```
    try
    {
        writeln("(((((((((");
        latestdtonpage = dts.sort!((a,b) => a>b).front; //latest date-time. from page. 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
        {
            writeln("Can't select the latest Date from parsed date");
            writeln(e);
        }
```

But output in case of exception is next (no exception text):

```
(((((((((
core.exception.AssertError@C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\array.d(73
9): Attempting to fetch the front of an empty array of DateTime
----------------
0x0051C4C9 in _d_assert_msg
0x00468E78 in pure nothrow ref @property @nogc @safe std.datetime.DateTime std.r
ange.__T11SortedRangeTAS3std8datetime8DateTimeS473app19StackOverflowParser5parse
MFAyaZ9__lambda2Z.SortedRange.front() at C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\
std\range.d(8418)
0x0044F908 in void app.StackOverflowParser.parse(immutable(char)[]) at D:\code\T
rendoMetr\source\app.d(173)
0x0044F700 in app.StackOverflowParser app.StackOverflowParser.__ctor(app.DBConne
ct) at D:\code\TrendoMetr\source\app.d(150)
0x0044F199 in _Dmain at D:\code\TrendoMetr\source\app.d(33)
0x0052EDCA in D2rt6dmain211_d_run_mainUiPPaPUAAaZiZ6runAllMFZ9__lambda1MFZv
0x0052ED9F in void rt.dmain2._d_run_main(int, char**, extern (C) int function(ch
ar[][])*).runAll()
0x0052ECB5 in _d_run_main
0x00470198 in main
0x005667D1 in mainCRTStartup
0x76D1336A in BaseThreadInitThunk
0x772A9F72 in RtlInitializeExceptionChain
0x772A9F45 in RtlInitializeExceptionChain
Error executing command run: Program exited with code 1
```

How I can throw exception in this code?

Answer (score 10):

Your code throws an `AssertError`, indicating that `dts.sort!((a,b) => a>b)` is empty, and you shouldn't call `.front` on it. Instead, query `.empty` first, and act accordingly when it's true.

`AssertError` inherits from `Error` which in turn inherits from `Throwable` but not from `Exception`. So `catch(Exception e)` doesn't catch it. And you should not catch `Error`s anyway, as they indicate that the program is in an unrecoverable error-state.

`AssertError` in particular signals a logic bug in your program. Here: calling `.front` on an empty range. Don't catch `AssertError`, but fix your code instead.